# i want to retrieve unique values from my table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a table i have some of column have duplicate values i want to retrieve  unique values from my table  i used `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name` query and i got unique columns but my problem is i also want id of anyone of the duplicate value how can i retrieve that from using a single query ?
Eg

```
+----+------+------+
| id | name | po   |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | some |    2 |
|  2 | xyzs |    3 |
|  3 | frth |    2 |
|  4 | lopd |    3 |
|  5 | gtry |    2 |
+----+------+------+
```

i want to find unique po  and any one of its id

Output

some thing like this

```
po - 2 id - ( any of 1,3,5)
po - 3 id - ( any of 2 or 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) id, po 
FROM table_name
GROUPB BY po, id
```

Answer (score 2):

Just group them and get the max id or the min.

```
SELECT max(id), po FROM table_name group by po
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me on this, but you might be able to do something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table_name GROUP BY po
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which id you will get, then:

```
SELECT po,id FROM table GROUP BY po
```

If you wish to get first/last of the ids with that same po, you can add MIN(id)/MAX(id) as well:

```
SELECT po,MIN(id) as id FROM table GROUP BY po
```

You can also have *all* the ids for that po:

```
SELECT po,GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids FROM table GROUP BY po
```

Comment: you get an error with this because id its not contained in the group and you are not ussing an Aggregate function.

Comment: @LuisTellez TIAS. you will get a random id, no errors. (and no warnings either)

Comment: i get this error in Sql Server, tougth it would be the same on Mysql.

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'out_company.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @LuisTellez what is your table structure and what is your sql query? it is definitely not what i listed here. see this: http://pastebin.com/bTvLV2C6

Comment: @LuisTellez You'll get that error (or a similar one) on SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres (unless the other columns are functional dependent). But not in MySQL.